# Importing variables from class to class

Tags: python, class

My program has three classes and I want to create an array in the third class and import all the variables from the first and second class to the array of the third class.

For example, in this exercise we must create a program for a bank. We have our users, their accounts and the account manager. These are the three classes we have to create.
So in the third class we must make a menu, which should show us the following:

> 1. Create an account
> 2. Withdraw
> 3. Deposit
> 4. Print user's info
> 5. Exit

Also the program needs to get some information from the user like name, surname, address, telephone, email, ID and the current amount of the account.

```
class user:      #the first class
    def __init__(self,name,surname,address,telephone,email):
        self.name=n
        self.surname=s  
        self.address=a
        self.telephone=t
        self.email=e
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_surname(self):
        return self.surname
    def get_address(self):
        return self.address
    def get_telephone(self):
        return self.telephone
    def get_email(self):
        return self.email
    def print_user_info(self):
        print(self.name,self.surname,self.address,self.telephone,self.email)


class account:    #the second class
    def __init__(self,ID,user,balance):
        self.ID=i
        self.user=u
        self.balance=b
    def get_ID(self):
        return self.ID
    def get_user(self):
        return self.user
    def get_balance(self):
        return self.balance
    def print_account_info(self):
        print(self.ID,self.user,self.balance)
    def print_balance(self):
        print(self.balance)

class account_manager:    #the third class
    def __init__(self,accounts):
        self.accounts=sa   #My program stops here.Now i must create the arrey!
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt mean for the whole thing to come out like this!

Comment: No problem! Next time, use ctrl-K to format your code :)

Comment: I can't understand your goal. What do you mean by `import a variable to an array` ?

Comment: I think the goal is to pass in an array of `account`s to the constructor of `account_manager`

Comment: The third class need some characteristics.It needs to save the account of users into an arrey

Comment: So my problem is how to save name,surname,address,telephone,email,ID and the balance of an account into an arrey

Comment: ...by putting a `user` instance into a list? You should really follow a tutorial, this is pretty basic stuff (see e.g. http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F)

Comment: Ok then if you can help me please help me I am not a programmer I am newbie

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your meaning correctly, you can initialize the array of accounts as an empty list, and then provide a method that adds an account:

```
class accounts_manager(object):
  def __init__(self): 
    self.accounts = []
  def add_account(self,account):
    self.accounts.append(account)
```

Then if you call accounts_manager.add_account() for each account, self.accounts will contain all of the accounts.